# Add products in custom cart in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.5, php

I have created a page where I have images of some items like product1, product2, product3 etc. All the products are configurable products. Below that I have added a custom block for cart. Which contains list of all the above products(there are only 3 products I want to add) (see below)

```
Product1    $39 x 1     =     $39
Product2    $25 x 1     =     $25
Product3    $30 x 1     =     $30

TOTAL           $94
```

When I click on the image of the product, it will redirect to product, there are some attributes with quantity to select and one add to cart button. Now when I click on Add to Cart button I want the product price and quantity is added to its appropriate place. Suppose I selected product2 and 3 quantity the cart look like

```
Product1    $0 x 0          =     $0
Product2    $25 x 3     =     $75
Product3    $0 x 0          =     $0

TOTAL           $75
```

I am able to do till redirecting to products, but not able to do the next part that Add to Cart. I want to know the steps and what functions I need to create in which files?